# Execute readlink on a remote machine

Tags: ubuntu, remote-access, iscsi

I want to extract the attached iSCSI device of a remote machine

```
dev_by_path="/dev/disk/by-path/ip-10.1.1.240:3260-iscsi-iqn.2013-12.com.ryussi:swift1-lun-0"

DEVICE=`ssh -i key.pem root@10.0.0.2 'bash -s' << 'ENDSSH'
basename $(readlink $dev_by_path)
ENDSSH`
```

It gives error:

```
readlink: missing operand
Try `readlink --help' for more information.
basename: missing operand
Try `basename --help' for more information
```

However if I do

```
DEVICE=`ssh -i key.pem root@10.0.0.2 'bash -s' << 'ENDSSH'
basename $(readlink "/dev/disk/by-path/ip-10.1.1.240:3260-iscsi-iqn.2013-12.com.ryussi:swift1-lun-0")
ENDSSH`
```

then it executes successfully and `echo $DEVICE` gives `sda`.
How should I execute this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By quoting the string that ends the "here document", you've disabled subsitution for the variables contained within it.  Your $dev_by_path variable is defined on the local side, not in the remotely executing shell.  So, you want to expand that before executing the ssh command.

```
DEVICE=`ssh -i key.pem root@10.0.0.2 'bash -s' <<ENDSSH
basename $(readlink $dev_by_path)
ENDSSH`
```

Comment: Here's what i did:    `cmd_file=mktemp     echo "basename \$(readlink $dev_by_path)" > $cmd_file     DEVICE=``ssh -i $STORAGE_KEY.pem -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oUserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null root@$storage_ip 'bash -s' < $cmd_file`